# How to get Maven release to clone git submodules?

Tags: git, maven, git-submodules

I've got a Maven project with some git submodules linked. Everything works fine until I do a release:prepare or :perform, the clean checkout these targets perform does not contain the submodules (or in other words, git clone is not recursive).
I could not find a proper way to configure Maven to call git clone with the --recursive option.

I was thinking of using the scm provider configuration (http://maven.apache.org/scm/git.html) or simply to configure the release plugin directly in the pom.xml, but couldn't get it to work.

Thanks.

Comment: As far as i know it's not possible to work with submodules. In this case Maven assumes to have everything in one git repos instead of multiple. In my opinion if you have multiple git repos you have different maven modules which you can release independently.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just added the following plugin:

```
<!-- This is a workaround to get submodules working with the maven release plugin -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <id>invoke build</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <executable>git</executable>
        <arguments>
           <argument>submodule</argument>
           <argument>update</argument>
           <argument>--init</argument>
           <argument>--recursive</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Instead of update.sh you could use "git submodule update --init --recursive"

Comment: No, you can't. That just be too smart if you could actually write a command there... The `exec-maven-plugin` doesn't find something (says "not found" for something that is obviously there). You need to use the shell script (after making it executable with `chmod +x /path/to/script.sh`)

Answer (score 24):

Here's the same solution but without a script:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <inherited>false</inherited> <!-- only execute these in the parent -->
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>git submodule update</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <configuration>
                <executable>git</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>submodule</argument>
                    <argument>update</argument>
                    <argument>--init</argument>
                    <argument>--recursive</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This was super helpful and just what I needed. Thanks for posting!

Comment: Thanks, cloning works like this. But mvn release: prepare fails when it tries to commit the submodule poms. I get [ERROR] fatal: Pathspec 'basic-utils\pom.xml' is in submodule 'basic-utils'.