# Pull git submodule using maven exec plugin while exec mvn deploy

Tags: java, git, maven

I am trying to deploy my projects without update git submodule manually.
I am trying to use maven exec plugin to update submodule when i execute maven command.
My full project is like this:

```
s3s3l/
├── app
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── pom.xml.versionsBackup
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   └── target
├── common
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── pom.xml.versionsBackup
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   └── target
├── data
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── pom.xml.versionsBackup
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   └── target
├── excel
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── pom.xml.versionsBackup
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   └── target
├── http
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── pom.xml.versionsBackup
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   └── target
├── jdbc
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── pom.xml.versionsBackup
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   └── target
├── LICENSE.md
├── mail
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── pom.xml.versionsBackup
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   └── target
├── mybatis
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── pom.xml.versionsBackup
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   └── target
├── parent
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── pom.xml.versionsBackup
├── pom.xml
├── pom.xml.versionsBackup
├── README.md
├── redis
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── pom.xml.versionsBackup
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   └── target
├── resource
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── pom.xml.versionsBackup
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   └── target
├── security
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── pom.xml.versionsBackup
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   └── target
├── target
│   └── checkout
├── utils
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── pom.xml.versionsBackup
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   └── target
├── web
│   ├── bin
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── pom.xml.versionsBackup
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   └── target
└── websocket
    ├── bin
    ├── LICENSE
    ├── pom.xml
    ├── pom.xml.versionsBackup
    ├── README.md
    ├── src
    └── target
```

Here is my top level pom.xml:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.s3s3l</groupId>
    <artifactId>moudel-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <scm>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/S3S3L/s3s3l</developerConnection>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <inherited>false</inherited> <!-- only execute these in the parent -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>git submodule update</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>git</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>submodule</argument>
                                <argument>update</argument>
                                <argument>--init</argument>
                                <argument>--recursive</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.s3s3l</groupId>
        <artifactId>s3s3l-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>parent</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <modules>
        <module>parent</module>
        <module>web</module>
        <module>app</module>
        <module>excel</module>
        <module>http</module>
        <module>jdbc</module>
        <module>data</module>
        <module>mail</module>
        <module>mybatis</module>
        <module>redis</module>
        <module>resource</module>
        <module>security</module>
        <module>utils</module>
        <module>common</module>
        <module>websocket</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

this is the directory i execute maven command:

```
checkout
├── app
├── common
├── data
├── excel
├── http
├── jdbc
├── LICENSE.md
├── mail
├── mybatis
├── parent
├── pom.xml
├── pom.xml.versionsBackup
├── README.md
├── redis
├── resource
├── security
├── utils
├── web
└── websocket
```

all submodule directory is empty.

and i get this error:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_151, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-103-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.util.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution.scope < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.helpers.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /home/zwei/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from /usr/share/maven/conf/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from /home/zwei/.m2/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /home/zwei/.m2/repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for /home/zwei/.m2/repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.s3s3l:moudel-parent:pom:2.1.0: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/parent/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/web/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/app/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/excel/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/http/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/jdbc/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/data/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/mail/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/mybatis/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/redis/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/resource/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/security/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/utils/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/common/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/websocket/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/parent/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/web/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/app/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/excel/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/http/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/jdbc/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/data/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/mail/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/mybatis/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/redis/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/resource/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/security/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/utils/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/common/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 
[ERROR] Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/websocket/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist @ 

    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:422)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:419)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:410)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph(DefaultMaven.java:491)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.s3s3l:moudel-parent:2.1.0 (/home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml) has 15 errors
[ERROR]     Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/parent/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist
[ERROR]     Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/web/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist
[ERROR]     Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/app/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist
[ERROR]     Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/excel/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist
[ERROR]     Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/http/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist
[ERROR]     Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/jdbc/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist
[ERROR]     Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/data/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist
[ERROR]     Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/mail/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist
[ERROR]     Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/mybatis/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist
[ERROR]     Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/redis/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist
[ERROR]     Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/resource/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist
[ERROR]     Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/security/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist
[ERROR]     Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/utils/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist
[ERROR]     Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/common/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist
[ERROR]     Child module /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/websocket/pom.xml of /home/zwei/github/s3s3l/target/checkout/pom.xml does not exist
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```

it seems maven exec plugin configuration not working. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of task was described before as working here: "[How to get Maven release to clone git submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29796988/6309)"

But: it did not have the line `<inherited>false</inherited>`.

It must run in the top folder of the project (where the git repo is cloned), *not* in the `target/checkout subfolder`, which is not a git repository.

Comment: when using mvn release plugin release:perform. maven will checkout git repo into target/checkout and execute deploy in this folder. folder checkout is a git repo

Comment: @kehw_zwei OK, so try https://stackoverflow.com/a/7446233/6309 (writing a script, in order to have more details: you can add for instance a git status in that script, to see the state of the checked out repo)